# Yii: Theme support for components?

Tags: php, yii, themes

I was wondering if yii components are also supporting the theme feature? In my environment right now a component is only considering files within the `component/views/` folder.
Now that I am also using themes it would be nice to tell the component to look for the view under the `themes/themeName/` folder.

Using the method below I can work around this but it certainly doesn't feel like this is the yii-way to do it.

```
protected function renderContent()
{
    $view = './../../../themes/'.Yii::app()->theme->name.'/views/viewName';
    $this->render($view);
}
```

Do you know of a more elegant solution to achieve this?

Comment: unfortunately, yii doesn't support themeing on components. but it does on widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any theming on components. Mainly because they're not intended to be rendering content for anything. Nothing wrong with that though, sometimes it's required.

Easiest solution is probably to just make it more readable, using path aliases always helps:

```
protected function renderContent()
{
    $view = 'webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->theme->name.'.views.viewName';
    $this->render($view);
}
```

Or you could add a method the component, or extend CComponent to get it across all components if you want it:

```
public function getViewsPath(){
    return 'webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->theme->name.'.views';
}
```

Or you could set a path alias:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('theme','webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->theme->name);
```

Then you could use that anywhere in your application provided you run it at an early enough point in the process.

Comment: Where would you run `Yii::setPathOfAlias()`?

Comment: That depends entirely on your application. At the top of the component class file? But then it won't be global, just local to whatever is loaded after that component. Possibly in an extended version of `CController`, that won't apply to console commands though.  It's a little messy but it could always just go at the top of your config file if there really is nowhere else.